# Safari image rendering bug

Tags: html, css, browser, image, safari

Has anybody else encountered this.  Whenever the images are intially loaded by the browser it only shows the last-half of the image.  Then when I mouse over anywhere in the green section it immediately displays the rest of the image.

What you're seeing here is a `<div>` with a background-image and a `<img>` located within said `<div>`.

I'm encountering this issue using Safari 3.2.3 for Windows and my colleagues have seen this using the Mac version.  None of the other browsers I have tested this in seem to show the same bug.  I've tested in IE8, IE7, IE6, FF3, Chrome, and Opera.

Let me know if you've heard of any fixes.  Thanks.

[Safari Image Bug http://www.pixelwhiskey.com/images/safari_image_bug.jpg](http://www.pixelwhiskey.com/images/safari_image_bug.jpg)

Comment: Try posting a bug report at http://bugs.webkit.org

Comment: Can you check out these Elements in the Safari Web Inspector to see what styles are being applied to them?

Comment: Without seeing the code it's impossible to say if this is a bug in Safary or (the more likely case) in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using PNGs instead if GIFS

Answer (score 0):

I've seen issues similar to this with IE rendering solved by setting height: 1% to the affected div or to an element nested within it.  I've never seen it in Safari though.

Comment: Yeah, I've fixed issues in the past with that as well.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Inspect all of the elements near the image in Firebug (yes, I know the problem is in Safari) and make sure none of them has the wrong size for any reason, and none of them has excessive padding that encroaches the image you're not seeing correctly.  Also, try setting `overflow: visible;` on the style for various elements in the vicinity; I've seen mouseover flickers in the past, but nothing that couldn't be overcome with CSS.

Comment: Thank you.  We refactored and we solved the issue.  Still don't know why this was doing this in safari.  I'll take your suggestions and play around with it in the old code.  I'll let you know what works and what doesn't.  Again, thanks.